# Transform tuple to matrix in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an rdd list of tuples and values that looks like this. There are thousands of different pairings.

```
(A, B), 1
(B, C), 2
(C, D), 1
(A, D), 1
(D, A), 5
```

I want to transform the tuple value pairs into a matrix that corresponds to the pairs. I didn't see any easy way to do this in spark.

```
+---+------+------+------+------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |
+---+------+------+------+------+
| A | -    | 1    | NULL | 1    |
| B | NULL | -    | 2    | NULL |
| C | NULL |      | -    | 1    |
| D | 5    | NULL | NULL | -    |
+---+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: scala ok as option?

Comment: Sure would prefer Java, but I can probably figure it out.

Comment: my advice, do java. let me look

Comment: do scala I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best effort, but cannot get rid of a column name using spark-sql (which you state).
Just pivoting with natural order.
Try it, added extra tuple.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
// Note sure what difference is between ("A", "B"), 1 or "A", "B", 1
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(  (("A", "B"), 1), (("B", "C"), 2), (("C", "D"), 1), (("A", "D"), 1), (("D", "A"), 5), (("E", "Z"), 500) ))

// Can start from here in fact
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2))

val df = rdd2.toDF()

// Natural ordering, but cannot get rid of _1 column in a DF (spark sql)
df.groupBy("_1").pivot("_2").agg(first("_3"))
  .orderBy("_1")
  .show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|_1 |A   |B   |C   |D   |Z   |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|A  |null|1   |null|1   |null|
|B  |null|null|2   |null|null|
|C  |null|null|null|1   |null|
|D  |5   |null|null|null|null|
|E  |null|null|null|null|500 |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```